# GCD input number

Tags: java, eclipse, greatest-common-divisor

I would need help to where i can manually add the input numbers within the script. If you see that a= 273 and b=108 I would like that to print the actually GCD but I am not actually getting the correct input. I am doing something simple but it is still not working. Also would this put in absolute terms, meaning if i put a negative will it make it a positive.

Edit: I am not trying to use a scanner class.

```
public class Divisor 
{
    private static int a;
    private static int b;
    {
    a= 273;
    b=108;
    }
    private static int returnNumber(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return a;
        }
        return returnNumber(b, a % b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(returnNumber(a, b));
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use the Scanner class? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Another option would be command line arguments: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Do some simple research.

Comment: I am not trying to actually have the user input it in. I mean just make A a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Scanner` from `java.util`, e.g.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    int b = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(a + " " + b);
```

Or `BufferedReader` from `java.io`:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    System.out.println(a + " " + b);
```

The previous snippet assumes each number is in a different line.

BTW, it's a good idea to put these lines inside a `try-catch` block with `IOException`.

**EDIT:** As @musical_coder mention, you can also use command line arguments, here is an example:

```
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    System.out.println(a + " " + b);
```

In this case you should run you program with:

```
$ java Divisor <first number> <second number>
```

Comment: I would not be using a scanner class sorry if it is confusing.